# What Schema should I Implement for food item?

Tags: schema.org, local-seo

I am working on a food delivery website. I am able to find `MenuItem` schema but it is for listing page. All I want to implement Schema format for a single Item, say for `Italian Pizza` on the individual food item page. I am confused which one should I pick, `Product` or `MenuItem`? I also want to show delivery time.

Comment: Who is going to use the schema?  Unless you know that it isn't worth wasting your time on it.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Not sure what do you mean. It is obviously for Google.

Comment: In what way?  Google doesn't have a rich snippet for a food item.  If there is no rich snippet, there is no benefit.  Google doesn't use schema markup for ranking purposes.   Here is the list of rich snippets that Google supports: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/search-gallery

Answer (score 1):

There is no particular food item schema markup on its own as you describe. There is menu item which is a part of the menu schema however as mentioned by @StephenOstermiller Google does not have a rich snippet for food items at this point so there is no real advantage to putting in the schema markup for a food item. There is the product schema option but this is not so much aimed at food products as products in general.